# avoiding duplicate transient instance in nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, duplicate-data, transient

My main entity (Account) graph looks like the following:

Account

- Manager

  SalesPerson

  Trader

The Manager, SalesPerson and Trader entity are of type person. Now while creating the main entity (along with inner entities) I need to create a new Person if it doesnt already exist. This introduces a problem, where in if the same (new) person is supposed to be associated with lets say SalesPerson and Trader, I want the same transient entity that was created to be associated with both. But instead I end up creating duplicate transient instances of the Person object which creates duplicates in the system. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Could you provide sample code demonstrating your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? In what "system", the database?

Comment: Lets say while creating the Account entity I have the same employee as SalesPerson and Trader, and this is a new employee that will be created when I save the Account entity. When I query the db to check if the emp already exists I will not find it. So I will say accountObj.SalesPerson = EmployeeFactory.CreateEmployee(employeeId). In the next step for the Trader, I will en up doing the same because the emp is not yet saved. As a result, Trader and SalesPerson have been assigned the same emp but in db I ended up creating duplicate records when I saved accountObj. How do I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the Person object to the db as soon as you create it? Then it will be in the db, and when you check for it, there it is. If you are using a native primary key nHibernate will save it to the database when you call Save. If you are not using native primary key, you will have to call flush.

Alternatively, keep track of recently saved Person's, and check there first.

Comment: It will not happened. Nhibernate collect queries until Commit/Flush. Only when you use native primary key NHibernate must flush to db.

Comment: Good point. When I say "to the db" I mean the record is in the database. I have updated the answer to hopefully avoid any further confusion.